# Twitter API Integration in iphone application

Tags: iphone, twitter

I am integrating this Twitter API in my project.

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/twitter-api-iphone/

This is running well with my App. but I want to sure that is it valid or authorize API for Twitter ? Will I not get any problem in future or from app store ? Although this is looks good and it is also asking for CnsumerKey and COnsumerSecretKey.

Please know me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a valid Oauth API.You won't get any problem in app store.